# Resize Image to certain size while retaining aspect ratio, crop image if necessary (iOS)

Tags: ios

I'm using UIImagePickerController to choose an image from my Camera Roll and resizing it before uploading it to Parse.

I want to resize an image to certain size (let's say 750x1000) while retaining the aspect ratio of the original image. If necessary, I want to crop the image. I also want it to be easy to have different versions of the image (full size, thumbnail size). Right now I'm resizing only the height of the image. How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

**NewProductViewController.h**

```
@interface NewProductViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage scaledToHeight:(float) i_height;

@end
```

**NewProductViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addImage:(id)sender {
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        // A photo was selected
        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            // Save the image!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage scaledToHeight:(float) i_height {
    float oldHeight = sourceImage.size.height;
    float scaleFactor = i_height / oldHeight;

    float newWidth = sourceImage.size.width* scaleFactor;
    float newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

- (IBAction)createProduct:(id)sender {
    PFObject *newProduct = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Product"];

    UIImage *newImage = [self imageWithImage:self.image scaledToHeight:1000.f];
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [self imageWithImage:self.image scaledToHeight:410.f];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8f);
    NSData *thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnailImage, 0.8f);

    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.jpg" data:imageData];
    PFFile *thumbnailFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"thumbnail.jpg" data:thumbnailData];

    newProduct[@"imageFile"] = imageFile;
    newProduct[@"thumbnailFile"] = thumbnailFile;

    [newProduct setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one, it crops source image proportionally and then scales it to necessary size:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage size:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeZero;
    if ((sourceImage.size.width / size.width) < (sourceImage.size.height / size.height)) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(sourceImage.size.width, size.height * (sourceImage.size.width / size.width));
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * (sourceImage.size.height / size.height), sourceImage.size.height);
    }

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectZero;
    cropRect.origin.x = (sourceImage.size.width - newSize.width) / 2.0f;
    cropRect.origin.y = (sourceImage.size.height - newSize.height) / 2.0f;
    cropRect.size = newSize;

    CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([sourceImage CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), NO, 0.0);
    [croppedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I have an image that's 1400x1400. I'm using this code to crop it to 750x1000. `UIImage *firstImage = [self imageWithImage:self.firstImage size:CGSizeMake(750, 1000)];`. Your code resized the image to 1500x2000. Any reason as to why it's doing that. Also, is there a way to make sure the image gets cropped from the center out? Right now it crops the image from the right side. Thanks.

Comment: @chrisbedoya I updated code to crop from center. Problem with `1500x2000` I can't reproduce. What device do you use for testing? Also how do you check the size of result image?

Comment: @chrisbedoya, looks like I understood, you are saving image to disk and then check its size in file system, right?

Comment: I'm uploading the images to Parse, that's how I'm checking the image sizes. It looks like the images are being resized to double the size that I'm specifying, but that's fine. Everything else works great. Thank you!

Comment: It's double sized because of that numbers in `size` variable are treated as 'points', not `pixels`. If you run this code on iPhone 6 it will 3x size. And its good if you are going to display these pictures on iPhone.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minions.png"];
CGSize destination = CGSizeMake(750, 1000);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destination);
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destination.width,destination.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *new = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 750, 1000)];
new.image = newImage;
[self.view addSubview:New];
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: It resizes the image but it doesn't keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

When scaling to precise width or height you may lose image resolution. So my solution is to crop to aspect ratio:

**Swift 3**

```
func cropImage(image: UIImage, to aspectRatio: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let imageAspectRatio = image.size.height/image.size.width

    var newSize = image.size

    if imageAspectRatio > aspectRatio {
        newSize.height = image.size.width * aspectRatio
    } else if imageAspectRatio < aspectRatio {
        newSize.width = image.size.height / aspectRatio
    } else {
        return image
    }

    let center = CGPoint(x: image.size.width/2, y: image.size.height/2)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: center.x - newSize.width/2, y: center.y - newSize.height/2)

    let cgCroppedImage = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)))!
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgCroppedImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

    return croppedImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method I created

```
    -(UIImage *)getRescaledImage:(UIImage *)image{
    int height = image.size.height;
    int width = image.size.width;
    int max = MOImageMaxHeightWidth;
    float divideFactor = 0;

    if(!(height > max) || !(width > max)){
        return image;
    }

    if(height > width){
        divideFactor = height/max;
    }else{
        divideFactor = width/max;
    }

    height = height/divideFactor;
    width = width/divideFactor;

    return [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
}


+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

MOImageMaxHeightWidth is a constant float value which you can give define for the max width/height. The aspect ratio of the image will be maintained. The variable divideFactor will take care of it and is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below UIImage Categories. Hope this will work for you too.

https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories

```
CGFloat scale = .5f;

CGFloat maxSize = 1632 * 1224;
CGFloat currentSize = croppedImage.size.width * croppedImage.size.height;

if ((currentSize / 2) > maxSize) {
    scale = maxSize / currentSize;
}

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(croppedImage.size.width * scale, croppedImage.size.height * scale);
__block UIImage *imageToSave = [croppedImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];
```